# didupdatelocations updating OCCASIONALLY

Tags: ios, google-maps, location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have no Idea what is going on but my program is updating locations only occasionally. I have the plist file updated to allow for the location services and I never stopupdatinglocations in my program.

I put:

```
NSLog(@"Test")
```

right after my didupdatelocations and it is rarely updating. What am I doing wrong?!

I have requestwheninuseauthorization, the locationmanager.delegate is set to self

Am i just in a bad area with bad internet connection?

Additionally, I am using the actual iphone when this problem occurs. when i use the simulator, it works perfectly fine and constantly updates its location. So i am baffled as to what is going on.

someone asked about my location manager

```
locationmanager = [[cllocationmanager alloc]init];
locationmanager.delegate = self;
locationmanager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: you haven't provided enough information for us to help you. Post your code that sets up the location manager and starts location updates. Specifically, what are your distanceFilter and desiredAccuracy settings?

Comment: made some edits to answer your question